# Combine Switch case with && to include other variables

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using some PHP from here that sends an email based on a dropdown selection in Contact Form 7. I would like it to only execute and send the email if one of three other inputs is the number 10

I've attempted combining the switch with && and || operators but it fails to execute as desired. I am limited by my learning here so I would appreciate any assistance you may be able to give.

/* cf7 autorespond switch */

## hook in to wpcf7_mail_sent - this will happen after form is submitted

add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', 'contact_form_autoresponders' );

## our autoresponders function

````
function contact_form_autoresponders( $contact_form ) {

    if( $contact_form->id==14 ){ #your contact form ID - you can find this in contact form 7 settings

        #retrieve the details of the form/post
        $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();                          

        #set autoresponders based on dropdown choice            
        switch( $posted_data['location'] ){ #your dropdown menu field name
                    case 'AB':
                    case 'AL':
                    case 'B':
                    case 'BA':
                    case 'BB':
                    case 'BD':
                    $msg="email a";
            break;

                case 'NW':
                case 'N':
                case 'E':
                case 'W':
                case 'SW':
                case 'SE':
                case 'WC':
                case 'EC':  
           ``` && if ( $posted_data['size1'] == 10 || $posted_data['size2'] == 10 || $posted_data['size3] == 10)  ```    
            $msg="email b";
            else $msg="email a";
            break;

        }


        #mail it to them
        mail( $posted_data['femail-610'], 'Thanks for your enquiry', $msg );
    }

}
````

So I would expect email 'A' to send if any of the first cases are selected from the form dropdown and email 'B' to send if any of the secondary case is selected but only if one of the three sizes equals 10 else it sends email 'A'.

Comment: Remove the backticks and `&&`, then fix the missing `'` and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use [`in_array()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) for this kind of checks.

Simply change your switch to an if statement and define 2 arrays with the values you want to compare against.

```php
$locationsForEmailA = ['AB', 'AL', 'B', 'BA', 'BB', 'BD'];
$locationsForEmailB = ['NW', 'N', 'E', 'W', 'SW', 'SE', 'WC', 'EC'];
if(in_array($posted_data['location'], $locationsForEmailA, true) || 
    in_array($posted_data['location'], $locationsForEmailB, true) && 
    !($posted_data['size1'] == 10 || $posted_data['size2'] == 10 || $posted_data['size3'] == 10)){
    $msg = "email a";
} else {
    $msg = "email b";
}
```

Comment: thanks for responding, in the fourth line should that read $locationsForEmailB as it has the 'and' operator' ?

Comment: thank you for the answer, with slight mods it worked, do you have any tips on how to add html to the response? thank you for your time

Comment: @BlaqJim That would be a separate question. If you have a new problem please do not hesitate to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

A little code analysis:

```
....
case 'SE':
case 'WC':
case 'EC':
```

Until here, the switch is a OR (`||`) of call `case` instructions above beginning from your last `break`. If you change the next part to:

```
   if ( $posted_data['size1'] == 10 
        || $posted_data['size2'] == 10 
        || $posted_data['size3] == 10 )
   {
        $msg="email b";
   }
```

... then the whole `if` condition is AND'ed to the cases above ⇒ `$msg="email b"` is only executed, if at least one of the cases is valid  **AND**  the following if condition is TRUE.

Comment: thanks for responding, so should your response be posted directly after the second 'break' ?

Answer (score 0):

Switches simply do not work like that.

You need to switch to an if/else-if pattern or use a lookup dictionary.